# Why are my paper-input elements not submitted by an iron-form?

Tags: polymer-1.0

The form below submits the email address (a gold-email-input) but not the name (a paper-input). Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I see that paper-input does not implement IronFormElementBehavior and can *force* things to work by adding this behavior to paper-input-bahavior.html but not a hack I want to leave in place.

```
<dom-module id='cv-email'>
  <template>
    <form is='iron-form' id='emailForm' method='post' action='/v1/email' class='email-form' content-type='application/json'>
      <paper-input name='name' label='Your name' required error-message='Please enter your name'></paper-input>
      <gold-email-input name='email' label='Your email address' required error-message='Please enter a valid email address'></gold-email-input>
      <br>
      <paper-button raised on-click='submitForm' class='button'>Submit</paper-button>
    </form>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'cv-email',
      submitForm: function () {
         this.$.emailForm.submit();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

For others stumbling on this question. The new version of paper-input now implements the IronFormElementBehavior. This is now working. Don't forget to put a "name" attribute on your  element or it won't be added to the JSON body.